# Как добавить ActionBar android встроенными средствами Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbar, android-themes

У меня есть приложение на андроид которое я сделал с Dark Action Bar, сам не понял как))) Но вот я пытаюсь сделать опять тоже самое в другой программе, что бы был хотя бы простой Action Bar. Уже все прошерстил: и манифест, и стили и просто темы но все равно не смог добиться что бы был action bar. Если будут вопросы или не понятен мой вопрос то в коментах уточню что будет нужно.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/

Comment: мне кажется что была проблема в том что у меня MainActivity extends Activity вместо extends AppCompatActivity